# JavaScript how to get geo location from ip address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, ip-geolocation

Is there a way to get Geo location from the IP address of the user?

If user agrees, I collect Geo Location using:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

but if the user refuses, I want to get it from the IP address although it is not accurate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only

Comment: Be aware that the free IP lookups have very stringent usage restrictions (certain limits per day/hour) and limited returned data. If you need a reliable and scalable service you would need to pay for one

Comment: @Alex I want to get GEO LOCATION from IP, and NOT the IP itself...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an external API such as freegeoip : https://freegeoip.net/

Example of json response :

```
GET call : http://freegeoip.net/json/2.4.44.12
Where "2.4.44.12" is the IP address
```

But there are many other API doing the same thing, just look over the web which one you want to use.